# How do you detect a redirect in an UIWebView iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, api-key

I am using Xcode for a social media network site and I have a quick about the login/ signup process. For instance, I have a UIWebView that is linked to the login API page. (ex. www.**_.com/api_login.php?) When the user logs in with their credentials on that page the website redirects them to the success page (www._**.com/api_success.php?) with the API authentication token that is stored in the iOS app for user specific tasks embedded in the website source code.

Here is my question: How can I tell Xcode to execute Javascript to grab the authentication token once it is on the (www.**_.com/api_success.php?) page? Keep in mind that the URL is specific to the user and has a user specific api key at the end of the link. (www._**.com/api_success.php?apiconnectkey=123456789)

Thanks in advance for help with this, 
Technology Guy

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I follow 100%, but here are some things to look at:

Implement UIWebViewDelegate in your view controller and set the delegate property, then implement this message

```
 -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:
```

Docs

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

This will let you see each URL that is being set on the web view.  So, you could grab apiconnectkey.

Also, you can execute JavaScript on the page with

```
  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getToken()"]
```

where `getToken()` is a function on the page.  This will return a string.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html